# Scala method types and methods as parameters

Tags: scala, methods, anonymous-function

In the following code example, I do not understand why the function fun can be passed as an argument to the method `addAction`. The method `fun` is of type `Unit`, while the method `addAction` expects a function of type `() => Unit`.

If `fun` is of type `() => Unit`, then why does the compiler complain that `fun` is of type `Unit`, when I try to add `fun` to the actions list: `actions = fun :: actions`?

```
package myscala

object MyScala {

  def fun() { println("fun1 executed.") }

  def addAction(a: () => Unit) {
    actions = a :: actions
  }

  var actions: List[() => Unit] = List()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // the following line would produce a compiler error (found: Unit, required: () => Unit), it's OK
    // actions = fun :: actions
    actions = (() => fun) :: actions // OK
    // I would expect the same compiler error here (found: Unit, required: () => Unit), but it's OK why?
    addAction(fun)
    actions.foreach(_()) // prints twice "fun1 executed"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take this as an introductory example:

```
def fun() { println("fun1 executed.") }

val a1 = fun
val a2: () => Unit = fun
```

Both lines compile and (thanks to type inference) they look equivalent. However `a1` is of type `Unit` while `a2` is of type `() => Unit`... How is this possible?

Since you are not explicitly providing type of `a1`, compilers interprets `fun` as a method `fun` call of type `Unit`, hence the type of `a1` is the same as type of `fun`. It also means that this line will print *fun1 executed.*

However, `a2` has explicitly declared type of `() => Unit`. The compiler helps you here and it understands that since the context requires a function of type `() => Unit` and you provided a method matching this type, it shouldn't call that method, but treat it as first class function!

You are not doomed to specify type of `a1` explicitly. Saying:

```
val a1 = fun _
```

Do you now understand where your problem is?

Comment: Yes, I do. This now looks obvious to me (it did not at all at that time). When the compiler is able to infer that a function type is expected, I may simply write `fun`, otherwise I have to make it explicit that I am passing a function. Thanks for the clear answers to all of you!

Comment: @Manu: Consider accepting an answer that you consider to be the best one (not necessarily this one)

Answer (score 5):

You need to write `fun _` in the first case to avoid calling the method and performing eta-expansion instead.

This will work:

```
actions = (fun _) :: actions
```

If you don't do this, then `fun` is evaluated.

For more details, see Section 6.7 (*Method Values*) of the [Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

As to why `fun` is not evaluated in the second case, it is because type inference can clearly conclude that `addAction` expects a function. By the way, the type of `fun` is technically `()Unit`, not `Unit`, that is, a method type, and not a value type. See Section 3.3.1 in the [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for more.

Comment: I'd rather recommend a lighter reading: [Programming in Scala Chapter 9](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/control-abstraction.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between methods and functions. In your case `actions` is a list of functions. When the compiler knows that a function is required (like in the case of `addAction`) it can automatically convert a method `fun` into a function. Now `::` is also a method, therefore the compiler also knows that it takes functions as parameters. But the problem is the syntactic sugar of the right-associative operator `::`. If you were to call it like a method: `actions.::(fun)` it will compile (although I can't test it at the moment). When writing `fun :: actions` the compiler thinks that `fun` is an expression and therefore evaluates it and since it "returns" a `Unit` you get your compiler error.

**EDIT**

Since I now have the possibility to test my hypothesis (which was wrong) here are your options:

```
// Usual syntax
actions.::[() => Unit](fun)
actions.::(fun: () => Unit)
actions.::(fun _)
// Operator syntax
(fun: () => Unit) :: actions
(fun _) :: actions
```

Comment: `actions.::(fun)` evaluates to `List[Any] = List(())`. It is still evaluating the function though. Wonder why is the List[()=>Unit] converted to List[Any]? co-variance?

Comment: Yes, `List[Any]` is the most precise type for a list that can contain `Unit`s and `()=>Unit`s. The `Unit`, viewed as `()` is what evaluating `fun` returns.